# How to purge tableview cells before cellforRowAt is called?

Tags: swift, tableview

I have the following code

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        //creating a cell using the custom class
        if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0) {


            var cell:UITableViewCell;
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "book", for: indexPath)
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none;


            self.ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                self.ref.child("featured").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    // Get user value
                    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                    let title = value?["title"] as? String ?? ""
                    self.featured = value?["url"] as? String ?? ""

                    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.frame.size.width, height: 24))
                    label.numberOfLines = 0
                    label.font = UIFont(name: "CeraPro-Medium", size: 20);
                    label.textColor = UIColor.black
                    label.text = NSLocalizedString("   Free Daily Pick", comment: "featured")
                    label.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
                    cell.addSubview(label)

                    if let image = value?["image"] as? String, image.isEmpty {
                        print("String is nil or empty.")
                    } else {
                        if let image = value?["image"]  {

                            let imageView = UIImageView();
                            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                                     y: 75,
                                                     width: cell.frame.size.width,
                                                     height: 150)
                            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                            imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

                            imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: image as! String), placeholderImage: nil)
                            cell.addSubview(imageView)

                            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10,
                                                              y: cell.frame.size.height-60,
                                                              width: cell.frame.size.width,
                                                              height: 50));
                            label.textColor = UIColor.black
                            label.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.5)
                            label.font = UIFont(name: "CeraPro-Bold", size: 16)
                            label.text = "  \(title)"

                            let view = UIView()
                            view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.frame.size.width, height: 150);
                            view.tag = 123
                            view.addSubview(imageView)
                            view.addSubview(label)
                            cell.contentView.addSubview(view)
                        }
                    }
                    // ...
                }) { (error) in
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }

            })

            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "book", for: indexPath) as! BookTableViewCell

            cell.cellIndex = indexPath
            cell.dataSource = self
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            var books = [Book]();

            let count = self.enterpriseBooks.count;
            if count > 0 && indexPath.section <= self.enterpriseBooks_2.count {
                books = self.enterpriseBooks_2[indexPath.section - 1]!;
            }

            if (indexPath.section == (count + 1)) {
                books = nytbooks;
            } else if (indexPath.section == (count + 2)) {
                books = trendingbooks;
            } else if (indexPath.section == (count + 3)) {
                books = newbooks
            }

            if (books.count > 0) {
                if (cell.collectionView === nil) {
                    cell.addCollectionView();
                    cell.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
            }
            return cell
        }
}
```

Here for section 0, row 0 - I show a featured image
For section 1, 2, 3 - I show a horizontal collection view of book images.

What's happening is by using dequeue function to get the table view cell, the table view is caching some table view cell content which overlaps each other. Is there a way to purge table view cells before cellForRowAt is called?

Comment: You really shouldn't be adding all of your views to the cell in `cellForRowAt`. Cells get reused which means that you could potentially be adding views to the same cell twice. The other thing I would recommend is to call `self.ref.observe` and `self.ref.child("featured").observeSingleEvent ` in another method. What you want to do is reload your cell once your data from `observeSingleEvent` is ready.

Comment: @Rob what do you mean by "You really shouldn't be adding all of your views to the cell "?

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically adding subviews to a cell seems a terrible idea to me. Try to use auto layout and xib files whenever possible.

Anyway, you theoretically could remove all the subviews from a dequeued cell and then adding them again.

```swift
for view in cell.subviews {
    view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

That said, there are better approaches to use a special cell in the first position, like [using different cell types](https://medium.com/@stasost/ios-how-to-build-a-table-view-with-multiple-cell-types-2df91a206429).

Answer (score -1):

well, to handle caching data you have to handle all else cases to assign appropriate values to UI Elements in case of nil/ failure scenarios. For an instance you have to assign nil to UIImageView's image property if image url is nil/ empty like this

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    //creating a cell using the custom class
    if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0) {


        var cell:UITableViewCell;
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "book", for: indexPath)
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none;


        self.ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            self.ref.child("featured").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                // Get user value
                let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                let title = value?["title"] as? String ?? ""
                self.featured = value?["url"] as? String ?? ""

                let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.frame.size.width, height: 24))
                label.numberOfLines = 0
                label.font = UIFont(name: "CeraPro-Medium", size: 20);
                label.textColor = UIColor.black
                label.text = NSLocalizedString("   Free Daily Pick", comment: "featured")
                label.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
                cell.addSubview(label)
                let imageView = UIImageView();

                if let image = value?["image"] as? String, image.isEmpty {
                    print("String is nil or empty.")
                    imageView.image = nil
                    // same goes for the label
                } else {
                    if let image = value?["image"]  {

                        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                                 y: 75,
                                                 width: cell.frame.size.width,
                                                 height: 150)
                        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

                        imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: image as! String), placeholderImage: nil)
                        cell.addSubview(imageView)

                        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10,
                                                          y: cell.frame.size.height-60,
                                                          width: cell.frame.size.width,
                                                          height: 50));
                        label.textColor = UIColor.black
                        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.5)
                        label.font = UIFont(name: "CeraPro-Bold", size: 16)
                        label.text = "  \(title)"

                        let view = UIView()
                        view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.frame.size.width, height: 150);
                        view.tag = 123
                        view.addSubview(imageView)
                        view.addSubview(label)
                        cell.contentView.addSubview(view)
                    }
                }
                // ...
            }) { (error) in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

        })

        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "book", for: indexPath) as! BookTableViewCell

        cell.cellIndex = indexPath
        cell.dataSource = self
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        var books = [Book]();

        let count = self.enterpriseBooks.count;
        if count > 0 && indexPath.section <= self.enterpriseBooks_2.count {
            books = self.enterpriseBooks_2[indexPath.section - 1]!;
        }

        if (indexPath.section == (count + 1)) {
            books = nytbooks;
        } else if (indexPath.section == (count + 2)) {
            books = trendingbooks;
        } else if (indexPath.section == (count + 3)) {
            books = newbooks
        }

        if (books.count > 0) {
            if (cell.collectionView === nil) {
                cell.addCollectionView();
                cell.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
```

}

In all the nil cases you are doing nothing with related UI element and that allows dequeueReusability to retain old content. Just assign nil or default value to UI elements in else / nil case, it will resolve your issue